# How to add custom buttons to menu bar extras?

Tags: menu-bar, customization

Is there an app/any way to add a button with an icon to the menu bar extra (right side of menu bar) which would trigger an action? (Action may be a keyboard shortcut trigger or a script) This would be very powerful when used alongside say keyboard maestro.

Example: Every time I click that button, it will trigger <kbd>⌘ Q</kbd>.

I know one way would be me just making an app to do so. But is there a shortcut creator/simpler maintainable way which simplifies the process?

---

I have searched a lot in google/reddit/stack exchange and the only proper solution I found is the new shortcuts app in Monterey in which you can add a shortcut to a menu bar dropdown. But it will be still 2 clicks away.